Trying to create a suit of playing cards using only CSS, JavaScript, and Fonts. Need to turn some symbols upside down in the main content too
Screenshot of current look
I need to turn half the suits upside down to complete the design.
The numbers and the suit below on the sides already have a CSS turning them, but how do I add the turn in my JavaScript to half of the actual suit-symbols in each card?
This is the CSS for the card and the first rotation:
.card {     
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    height: 90px;
    width: 65px;
    text-align-last: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: "Segoe UI Historic Regular", sans-serif, monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #f5f5e0ff;
    font-kerning: normal;
    letter-spacing: -0.2px;
    line-height: 7.5px;
    white-space: pre;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px -2.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)
}
.card.red {
    color: red;
}
.card.black {
    color: black;
}
.card::before,
.card::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: attr(data-value);
    white-space: pre;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.card::before {
    top: 3px;
    left: 1px;
}
.card::after {
    bottom: 3px;
    right:  1px;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

JavaScript:
class Card {
constructor(suit, value) {
this.suit = suit
this.value = value
    }

    get color() {
    return this.suit === "♣" || this.suit === "♠" ? "black" : "red"
    }


    getHTML() {
    const cardDiv = document.createElement("div")
        var val = this.value;
        var sui = this.suit;
        switch(this.value) {
            case "1": sui = this.suit;  break;
            case "2": sui = this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit;  break;
            case "3": sui = this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit;  break;
            case "4": sui = this.suit+"   "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"   "+this.suit;  break;
            case "5": sui = this.suit+"   "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"   "+this.suit;  break;
            case "6": sui = this.suit+"   "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"   "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"   "+this.suit;  break;
            case "7": sui = this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit;  break;
            case "8": sui = this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit;  break;
            case "9": sui = this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit;  break;
            case "10": sui = this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"\n"+this.suit+"    "+this.suit;  break;
    }

    cardDiv.innerText = sui
    cardDiv.classList.add("card", this.color) 
        if (this.value != "10") {
            cardDiv.dataset.value = `${" "+this.value+"\n"} ${this.suit}`}
        if (this.value == "10") {
            cardDiv.dataset.value = `${this.value+"\n"} ${this.suit}` }
    return cardDiv 
    }
}

Can I add the rotation in the switch section above somehow?
